# Fill Each Cell With Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am attempting to write a macro that will 

1)  store the value of each cell in column A in a variable `searchstring`

the pieces of code that *I Think* does this is

```
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To lr
      searchstring = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
```

2) Take the variable `searchstring` and determine if it exists in column A of the sheet called rsca.

4) If it does update column N with Yes

5) If it does not update column N with No

This is my full syntax, but everytime I step through my code it hits the For line and immediately jumps to the `End Function`  My worksheet has data in it, column A has roughly 40 rows to be precise (but this could fluctuate up or down, so I do not want to hardcode an end cell)

How should this syntax be altered so that it will achieve my desired result above?

```
Public Function CheckIfCurrent()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, searchstring As String, i As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("ers")

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
      searchstring = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
      With .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
         .Formula = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(searchstring, Sheets("rsca").Columns(1), 0)), "No", "Yes")
         .Value = .Value
      End With
    Next i        
End Function
```

Comment: your `lr` is not fully qualified, modify it to `lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` , or add `With ws` before and add `.` before

Comment: and `ws.Rows.Count` , which worksheet `With .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` belongs to ?

Comment: I modified my lr line with yours and I get the same result.  The row count should belong to Sheets("ers")

Comment: When you run it in debug mode, whae exactly happens ? getting an error ? what value is `i` ? what value is `lr` ?

Comment: No error, it says i = 0 lr output is 1

Comment: Though you have already accepted an answer, please refer to the one I just published. The method used in your original code and the accepted answer compares one by one the values in columns `A` of sheet `ers` however it updates the entire column `N` with that result, therefore at the end of the run column `N` shows in all cells the result of the last comparison as prior comparisons were overwritten in each loop. Just notice that column `N` and the end holds the same value in all updated cells.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Public Sub CheckIfCurrent()
    Dim searchstring As String
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ers")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            searchstring = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            With .Range("N2:N" & lr)
                .Formula = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(searchstring, Sheets("rsca").Columns(1), 0)), "No", "Yes")
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        Next i 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Same result.  It hits the for line and immediately stops.  No further processing.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh, what's in column B?

Comment: Column B on ers is blank, Column B on rsca has decimal values

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh, can you run the updated code and tell me what the Msgbox says?

Comment: lr outputs 1.  Which that does not make sense?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh ... and there's your issue! You need to make sure your data is in sheet `ers` column B

Comment: Column B is blank - can I check column A instead?  I thought that is what I was doing with the (.Rows.Count, "A") piece.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh, yep -- try updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139366/discussion-between-callumda-and-bellhopbydayametuercoderbynigh).

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding of the requirements:

Apply a formula, to column `N` of worksheet `ers`, that validates if the value in the same row of column `A` is present in column `A` of worksheet `rsca`.
The formula shall return `Yes` if the value is found and `No` otherwise.

As the objective is to return the desired result using an excel formula there is no need to loop trough any of the ranges involved.

This solution applies to the `Target Range` the following formula:

`=IF( ISERROR( MATCH( RC1, #rSrc, 0 ) ), ""No"", ""Yes"" )`

Where:

The `Target Range` is located in sheet `ers` at `N2:Nr` *(`r` is the last row with data in column `A`)*

`#rSrc` represents address of the `Source Range` located in sheet `rsca` at `A2:Ar` *(`r` is the last row with data in column `A`)*

The following code:

- Uses a constant to hold the excel formula.
- Gets the last row with data from each worksheet.
- Builds the Target and Source range.
- Updates the excel formula with the `source range address`.
- And applies the excel formula to the Target Range, leaving the resulting values.

Try this code:

```
Public Sub CheckIfCurrent_Published()
Const kFml As String = "=IF( ISERROR( MATCH( RC1, #rSrc, 0 ) ), ""No"", ""Yes"" )"
Dim rTrg As Range, rSrc As Range
Dim sFml As String

    Rem Set Target Range (Sheet `ers`)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ers")
        Set rTrg = .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    Rem Set Target Range (Sheet `rsca`)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rsca")
        Set rSrc = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    Rem Reset Formula
    sFml = kFml
    sFml = Replace(sFml, "#rSrc", rSrc.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=1))

    Rem Apply Formula
    With rTrg
        .FormulaR1C1 = sFml
        .Value = .Value2
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: See [Rem Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278825(v=office.15).aspx) or just select the word in the VBA editor and press [F1]

Comment: @user2676140. I presume you downvoted my answer? Care to explain why?